# How to effectively provide a token liquidity on uniswap for the first time?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, uniswap, smart-contract-wallets

I created 100.000 Tokens, now Id'like to provide liquidity on uniswap with 100$ (0.04 ETH) I have as of now (2022-02-26th), however these are my concerns:

What if someone bought all my tokens since it's cheaper (eg. 0.0000001 eth/token)?
If someone bought all, Do I just lost my tokens and does the person have power to manipulate the token's market?
Do I have to mint a fixed amount of tokens or create unlimited number?
What if I limit the number of tokens that a wallet can hold? but one person can have more wallets, I am confused.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

A person can only buy 5% of the total amount provided with the previous version of uniswap, with the current version you can set a range by yourself I presume.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).